# Why is the size of .NET Framework 4.0 installer smaller than 3.0/3.5?

Tags: .net, installation, footprint

As I can see, beta2 of .Net Framework 4.0 installation program is only 55MB, and it was 200+MB for .Net 3.5, What's happening?

Comment: This is the size of the /installation/ program, not the footprint of the installed framework: suggest you clarify the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET 3.5 size is that big because it contains the x64 version of the framework in the same package. The 2.0, 3.0 packages were separated for x86 vs x64. I guess 4.0 will adopt a separated approach too. 
This link explains it:
[link](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2008/01/10/7067719.aspx)

Comment: For info on the online vs offline installs for .Net 3.5, check out this blog post:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SmallestDotNetOnTheSizeOfTheNETFramework.aspx

Comment: There was IA64 too, not only x86 and x64 version.

Answer (score 1):

This follow on from the work done to optimise the framework for the Silverlight plug-in.

.net is now 10 years old, new techniques and just some good old fashioned spring cleaning of the code is before performed on version 4, to (hopefully) give us a sharper, more refined and more capable framework with the new version.

Comment: Thanks, I think so. But I wonder what exactly have they done that achieved this effect. Do they remove some Assemblies? Do they cut any Types? Do they used a new compression format?

Comment: Did they finally remove a few of the things that have been depreciated for years?

Comment: Citation required - do you have references? I don't believe /anything/ has been removed.